# If $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are non-identical sequences in $(0,1)$ that each sum to $1$, prove that $\sum \left(\frac{Y_i^2}{X_i}\right) > 1$.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

The LHS the inequality turns up in optimal portfolio analysis. The analysis makes sense if this expression is greater than 1. However, I am unable to prove it. Please let me know how to prove the inequality. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are not identical sequences.

Comment: Please format your question and add what you have tried so far to prove it.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what is even written here. But taking everything at face value, it’s false which can be seen by taking $Y_i=X_i$ for all $i$

Comment: The expression is equal to 1 if X_i=Y_i for all i. Assume there exists an i such that X_i!=Y_i.

Comment: Hint: Apply Cauchy Schwarz. Verify that equality doesn't hold because of your newly edited condition.

Comment: See also https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/

Comment: Thank you Calvin and Maximilian.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum \left(\frac{Y_i^2}{X_i}\right) &= \sum X_i \left(\frac{Y_i}{X_i}\right)^2\\
&> \left(\sum X_i \frac{Y_i}{X_i}\right)^2 && \text{Jenen Inequality}\\
&= 1
\end{align}

Since $u\mapsto u^2$ is not affine function and your sequence is not identical the inequality is strict.